# How to process values in CSV format in streaming queries over Kafka source?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm new to Structured Streaming, and I'd like to know is there a way to specify Kafka value's `schema` like what we do in normal structured streaming jobs. The format in Kafka value is 50+ fields syslog-like csv, and manually splitting is painfully slow.

Here's the brief part of my code ([see full gist here](https://gist.github.com/toddleo/0988d3334ffbbf772373186f126ba5ef))

```
spark.readStream.format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "myserver:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "mytopic")
  .load()
  .select(split('value, """\^""") as "raw")
  .select(ColumnExplode('raw, schema.size): _*) // flatten WrappedArray
  .toDF(schema.fieldNames: _*)                  // apply column names
  .select(fieldsWithTypeFix: _*)                // cast column types from string
  .select(schema.fieldNames.map(col): _*)       // re-order columns, as defined in schema
  .writeStream.format("console").start()
```

with no further operations, I can only achieve roughly 10MB/s throughput on a 24-core 128GB mem server. Would it help if I convert the syslog to JSON in prior? In that case I can use `from_json` with `schema`, and maybe it will be faster.

Comment: Even with JSON, you would be parsing a string and pulling fields out of it. There would be more data for Spark to process, potentially making it slower than CSV, or whatever you have now. My suggestion would be to look at possibly using Avro (Avro schema registry +Syslog Kafka Connect source), or another compact binary format like msgpack or Protobuf. And attempt to read that via Spark. Kafka itself has no schema

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the quick response. For now, I’d like to keep it simple, with text-based formats instead of introducing binary formats like Avro, adding extra complexity. There should be at least one performant format for tabular data along with the design of Structured Streaming, or there’s no point to have it work with  DataFrame API.

Comment: Well, the thing with Avro or Protobuf is that the schema and types are built into the Protocol. And you can do nested field rather than flat "columns". I do not believe you can stream Parquet or ORC columnar formats through Kafka

Comment: @cricket_007 with my rsyslog + omkafka setup, there seems no easy way to transfer using Avro. Besides, all these computation runs on a single server, so it doesn’t look efficient to convert to Avro then convert it back.

Comment: I believe there are solutions like Logstash/Filebeat or Fluentd that can output into different formats such as Avro into Kafka. Otherwise, it's not really clear where your bottleneck is. For example, is there only one partition that you are processing?

Comment: @cricket_007 There’s 16 partitions in the topic, I also tried master-slave Spark deployment instead of local[*] but made no much difference. From the Spark master Web UI I can tell all the 48 logic cores and 80 out of 128 gigs of RAM were allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to specify Kafka value's schema like what we do in normal structured streaming jobs.

No. The so-called output schema for kafka external data source is fixed and cannot be changed ever. See [this line](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.1/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaSource.scala#L143).

> Would it help if I convert the syslog to JSON in prior? In that case I can use from_json with schema, and maybe it will be faster.

I don't think so. I'd even say that CSV is a simpler text format than JSON (as there's simply a single separator usually).

Using `split` standard function is the way to go and think you can hardly get better performance since it's to split a row and take every element to build the final output.

Comment: Does 10MB/s looks normal to you, considering I'm running the simple code on a 24-physical-core + 128GB sever? I'm also advised to wrap raw data into groups of binary packages before transforming to Kafka, would that help? And where else can I find the bottleneck?

Comment: I noticed that Console Sink may related to my performance issue, the document writes, "This should be used for debugging purposes on low data volumes...". I limited the size of output DataFrame by filtering, and changed to ElasticSearch sink, now the job can handle at least 60MB throughput with moderate CPU and memory consumption.